# How to get the rest task delay time in tarantool 1.6 queue

Tags: lua, queue, tarantool

I'm trying to use tarantool fifottl queue to store some deferred tasks in it.

I have to use following interface to store the task:

```
queue.tube.tube_name:put({ some_key, 'some_data' }, { delay = 80 })
```

How can I retrieve current task delay without changing task's state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly:
There's no way to do this using Queue API.

Long answer:
One of the basic rules of this queue is: "no one know about task, if it's not taken", so it's against this rule.

Dirty hack:
You can take this information from Tarantool space:

```
local states = require('queue.abstract.state')

local state, time = *queue-instance*.space:get{*TASK_ID*}:unpack(2, 3)}

if state == states.DELAYED then
    -- task is delayed, so time in `time` is the right time
end
```